# eclipse neon 3 UI Glitch Marketplace no longer accessible

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-neon

Good Morning, Good Evening, Good Afternoon everyone. :P Today, I ran into a problem shortly after I updated the Eclipse IDE from Neon 2 to Neon 3. It does appear that [I am no longer able to access the MPC (Market Place Client)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpGEZ.png). The help menu no longer has any options for MPC.

I do clarify that I was able to access it once after the update, and I used it to try and download a few plugins that went missing after the update. But for some reason, when I restarted eclipse to finalize the plugin install, the help menu no longer had any links to it. (And the link in the Welcome Screen does nothing in case somebody were to mention it, tho it did give a small notification once telling me there was an exception trying to execute the UI command.)

I am running Arch Linux x86_64 and updated eclipse through pacman in case that's a needed detail. I do believe this to be a bug, but if nobody else is experiencing this, I would definitely appreciate some help.

Comment: Update: I have gone through uninstalling, deleting everything in '/usr/lib/eclipse', and then reinstalling eclipse. I confirm this DOES NOT work, and I have no explanation as to why it does not work. I do not fully understand the nature of the problem, I seriously need help.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't entirely understand the problem, but I fixed it by deleting everything in `/home/[user]/.eclipse`. I can now go about installing updates, new plugins, and the like again.